# Counting binary trees

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, trees

How to get a closed form for the number of different trees possible for a labeled binary tree with $n$ leaves labeled from $1$ to $n$?

I have derived a recurrence formula, but unable to find a way to solve it.

My formula is :

if there are $n$ terminal nodes in the tree, then

T(n)=$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{i} *T(i)*T(n-i)$

The result should be a closed form equation, like $T(n)=\frac{(2n - 3)!}{2^{n-2}(n - 2)!}$

It is different from Catalan number.

Explanation:

For $3$ terminal nodes, number of possible trees is $3$. These are :

[image]
[image]
[image]

However following trees are equivalent, and counted only once:

[image] [image][image]

Comment: It appears you are talking about _unordered_ trees, in which case the linked question would not be a duplicate. Can you confirm, how many trees should there be when there are $n=3$ terminal nodes? Is it one or two?

Comment: @ Mike Earnest : Yes, the grouping is not ordered, but the terminal nodes are labelled. For $n$ terminal nodes (say $n1,n2,n3$), total number of binary trees possible, is 3. As I am unable to draw trees in the comment, I am editing my question, to give the 3 trees possible. Also, while giving this explanation, I realize, my recurrence formula is wrong.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001190 counts unlabeled binary trees.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002572 also counts binary trees.

Comment: Is this what you are asking? [Number of Unordered Binary Tree and Its Recurrence Relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2538905/number-of-unordered-binary-tree-and-its-recurrence-relation)

Comment: @rogerl : I am looking for derivation of a closed form solution of the kind of tree mentioned there.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question because it should not have been closed; the linked question is not a duplicate, as this question is asking for a proof of a closed form formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the closed form solution is $T(n)=(2n-3)!/(2^{n-2}\cdot (n-2)!)$. Another way of writing this is
$$
(2n-3)\times (2n-1)\times \dots \times 3\times 1,
$$
also written as $(2n-3)!!$.

Here is the proof. Imagine you have a binary tree with $n$ leaves, and you delete the leaf labeled "$n$." The result is now almost a binary tree; the only problem is that one of the internal nodes will have only one children (namely, the node which originally had "$n$" as a child). This can be fixed by "contracting" that internal node. Here is an example when $n=4$:

```
    __.__            __.__            __.__    
   /     \          /     \          /     \   
  .       .        .       .        .       3  
 / \     / \      / \     /        / \       
1   2   3   4    1   2   3        1   2
```

Now, imagine the process in reverse. How many ways are there to take a tree $T$ with $n-1$ children, and add in a leaf node labeled $n$? Now you need to choose a node $v$ in $T$, and add an new internal node $w$ just above $T$. The parent of $w$ is the original parent of $v$, and the children of $w$ are $v$ and the new leaf node labeled $n$. Since $T$ has $2n-3$ nodes total ($n-1$ leaves, $n-2$ internal), you can add a new leaf to $T$ in $2n-3$ ways.

We have shown that for every tree with $n-1$ leaves, there are exactly $2n-3$ corresponding trees with $n$ leaves. That is, $$T(n)=(2n-3)\times T(n-1).$$ By induction, this proves that $T(n)=(2n-3)\times (2n-1)\cdots 3\times 1$. Explicitly, every tree with $n$ leaves can be built by adding the leaves number $2$ to $n$ one a time starting from the tree with a single leaf, and there are $2i-3$ ways to add leaf number $i$.

Comment: I got this idea from the answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716221/how-many-ways-to-write-a-commutative-non-associative-product-of-n-terms/